# Rails 3 how do I update the page with a recursive loop (building tree graph)?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, recursion, tree

I have a following situation.

In the model I am populating a table, which has a tree-like structure. I have a Graph model that has_many :nodes and Node model that has a "content" column that is populated during by the following:

```
class Graph < ActiveRecord::Base

   def start_collecting
    self.content_collection(self.nodes.first)
   end

   def content_collection(root)
    root.children.all(:order  => "idx DESC").each do |node|
    #Here the function in Node model is called, that populates 'content' column in node's table.
     content_array << node.content.to_s
     self.children_content = content.array
     self.save!
     child.collect_content
     if !node.children.blank?
      self.content_collection(node)
     end
    end
   end
```

The question is.. I want to have the progress being displayed on the web page (app/views/graphs/show.html.erb). So far I am doing this:

```
 setInterval(function(){
   var text = <%= array_or_string_for_javascript(@graph.children_content)%> ;
   var pjs = Processing.getInstanceById("graphsketch");
   pjs.update(text);
 }, 3000);
```

So that I am just redrawing the content of @graph.children_content on screen every 3 seconds.. I wonder what would be the best way to draw the contents of each @node.content with this timed refresh? Obviously if I just write an .each loop in show.html.erb I will keep getting the content of the last @node in the loop... Basically I wonder how to translate the loop from the above model onto the view and make the progress visible?

Hope this is clear enough, please let me know if I should explain better...

EDIT ::

So following the advice, now I have in graph_controller.rb:

```
def getstatus
  @graph = Graph.find(params[:id])
  @graph_so_far = @graph.get_graph  
  respond_to do |format|
    format_js
  end
end
```

in Graph.rb:

```
def get_graph(root = self.nodes[0], word_ary = [])
  @root = root
  @root.children.all(:order  => "idx DESC").each do |child|
   n_node = (child.depth*2).to_s+child.content
   word_ary << n_node
   child.parent_relation.collect_videos_multiple_cats
    if !child.children.blank?
     self.get_graph(child, word_ary)
    end
   end
  return word_ary
end
```

In graphs/show.html.erb :

```
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(function(){
    var idx  = "<%= @graph.id %>";
    $.get("getstatus/", {idx} )
      },1000);
 });      
  </script>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "pjs" %>
<canvas id="graphsketch" data-processing-sources="/assets/pjs/graphBuilder2_2.pde"></canvas>
```

In graphs/getstatus.js.erb

var text = <%= array_or_string_for_javascript(@sentence_so_far)%> ;
   var pjs = Processing.getInstanceById("graphsketch");
   alert(text);
   pjs.update(text);

The alert in getstatus.js.erb never fires.

In routes (of course):

```
 resource :graphs do
   collection do
     get 'getstatus'
   end
 end
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot for the help again..

Comment: getstatus.js.erb should be in app/views/graphs,  is it?

Comment: ah. just actually changed format_js to format.js and everything works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also,  i think the call to the AJAX should be more like

$.get("/graphs/getstatus");  I use jquery always,  so I'm not very familiar with javascript WITHOUT jquery!!!!

Comment: Opps,  my bad,  sorry a common problem with me!  always check what I post for obvious typos, etc.  Glad you're running!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me make sure I understand,  you want to show the graph in it's entirety as it's growing,  refreshing every 3 second, correct?

First thing I'd do is create an AJAX action in the GraphController that get's the full content  of the graph so far

```
def getstatus
  @graph_so_far = Graph.???  
  respond_to do |format|
    format_js
  end
end
```

Of course you'll have to add a new route

Then in getstatus.js.erb (in the same directory as show.html.erb)

```
var text = <%= array_or_string_for_javascript(@graph_so_far)%> ;
var pjs = Processing.getInstanceById("graphsketch");
pjs.update(text);
```

That get's you your first update,  now all you have to do set a timer,  and kick off the same AJAX call after 3 seconds, I use jquery.timers.js,  but whatever,  after 3 seconds send another AJAX request to the URL /graph/getstatus, (or whatever you called your route), starting the cycle over again.

Comment: Sorry,  you'll also have to make the initial AJAX call to get things started,  you just have to send an AJAX request to URL /graph/getstatus , probably after the DOM loaded event.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it now.. I don't quite understand - what is "???", can you explain please?

Comment: Oh I guess it's the Model call.. I need a break.

Comment: I added the updated code to the question, can you please have a look?